# Objective C Acessing NSMutableDictionay inside NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutabledictionary

I am a newcomer to objective C and I have serious problems in accessing `NSMutableDictionary`s.

I have two objects (`Network` and `Beacon`), and I want to create a `NSMutableDictionary` of Networks with a `NSMutableDictionary` of `Beacon`s inside.

```
Network.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Network : NSObject{
    NSString *id_network;
    NSString *major;
    NSString *active;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *status;
    NSMutableDictionary *beaconsDictionary;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id_network;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *major;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *active;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *beaconsDictionary;
@end

Beacon.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Beacon : NSObject{
    NSString *id_beacon;
    NSString *major;
    NSString *minor;
    NSString *active;
    NSString *detected;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id_beacon;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *major;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *minor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *active;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detected;

@end
```

I can create the `NSMutableDictionary` like this:

```
    Beacon *beacon = [[Beacon alloc]init];
        beacon.id_beacon=@"1";
        beacon.major=@"1";
        beacon.minor=@"1";
        beacon.active=@"1";
        beacon.detected=@"0";
    NSMutableDictionary *beaconDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   [beaconDic setObject:beacon forKey:beacon.id_beacon];

    Network *net = [[Network alloc]init];
        net.id_network=@"1";
        net.major=@"1";
        net.active=@"1";
        net.name=@"network 1";
        net.status=@"1";
        net.beaconsDictionary=beaconDic;


    NSMutableDictionary *networkDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 
  [networkDic setObject:net forKey:net.id_network];
```

Ok, but now how can i access to beacon property "detected" directly and modify it?

I know this this is a very bad example, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to have a network id and a beacon id to get where you need to go.  It would looks something like:

```
Network *net = networkDic[netId];
Beacon *beacon = net.beaconsDictionary[beaconId];
beacon.detected = newDetectedValue;
```

This is for arbitrary network ids and beacon ids.  You can hardcode values if you wish.

Edit:
It's worth noting in your example code that you can use the more modern dictionary assignment.  Rather than `[dictionary setValue:value forKey:key];`, you can do `dictionary[key] = value;`.  It's, of course, personal preference but you're very likely to see the latter in more recent things and I find it to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks!! And this will modify  the dictionarys also if the networkDic is defined in a singleton to be accesible for many classes?

Comment: Yes. If you have access to the networkDic, singleton or otherwise, this will appropriately change the 'detected' property on a beacon.  Although it doesn't appear you're quite at this point yet, I would recommend being wary of thread safety when accessing and mutating networkDic if it's going to be accessible from many parts of a system.  Just a thing to look out for, not really related to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your `Network` and `Beacon` objects back by providing keys that match their keys in the dictionary:

```
NSString *nwKey = @"1";
Network *n = networkDic[nwKey];
NSDictionary *bDict = n.beaconsDictionary;
NSString *bnKey = @"1";
Beacon *b = bDict[bnKey];
```

**Note:** This is the new syntax. Here is the old one:

```
NSString *nwKey = @"1";
Network *n = [networkDic objectForKey:nwKey];
NSDictionary *bDict = n.beaconsDictionary;
NSString *bnKey = @"1";
Beacon *b = [bDict objectForKey:bnKey];
```